# Will wine get intergration into Unity Dash? And if so, how?

Tags: unity, 11.04, wine

Will Natty's Unity Dash have wine integration like the ubuntu-desktop session? It would be nice if it had it's own category for Wine (if installed).

Comment: Perhaps you might want to ask this question directly to the WINE team.

Comment: I can, and I probably will. However as an end user, I am not always sure who to ask such questions. It seems interesting that people in a "ASK" website are always complaining that we're asking the wrong questions, or to the wrong people. Personally I believe there are no bad questions, only lazy answers. But the point of asking it here is so that everyone can see the answer.

Comment: There is no "Wine Team", it's just me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer, bluntly, is *"No, unless Mark gives me a job."*

I've had designs for better integrating Wine with Ubuntu for some time, however progress has been slow as it's an awful lot of time and most of my day is spent doing "real work" and the day to day tasks of package maintenance.  You can see some of this such as [integrating Wine into Software Center](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-n-desktop-wine-software-center) (might not be finished by Natty), or the [better Wine integration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/karmic-wine-integration) specs.

It would be neat to use things like the Unity Places API to make Wine really slick, but at the moment I barely have enough time to make sure things aren't horribly broken.

Comment: I appreciate your contributions to the community, and your honest answer. Thanks mate ;)